# Delphi - Query open on DataModule invalidate AutoCommit? Strange bug with 10.2 Toyko

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8, firedac, autocommit, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have a datamodule with an FDQuery on, all is set how it should be, and I open it in the 'OnCreate' event of the datamodule. This datamodule is linked in another form that has other queries, datasets, tables and navigators on.

I used to use Delphi XE8, and all worked fine.

Now I'm using Delphi 10.2 tokyo, struggling with a strange bug:
(I State that the FDConnection used for all queries and DataSets is the same and has AutoCommit property set to True)

- Suppose i edit a field in a DataSet on the form and post it. The connection commit it and I can see this modify in the DB.
- Now I create an instance of the DataModule, so it creates the query and **open** it.
- If I try to edit again that DataSet and post it, no commit happens and the modify is not present in the DB, remaining only on this transaction.

Recently I discovered that this happens only if the query is opened in the 'OnCreate' event and remain open. If I Close it immediately afterwards having opened it, all works fine. If I open it after the creation of the DataModule instance, all works fine.

How can I fix this, leaving the query's opening in the OnCreate event?

NB: AutoCommit property is always True, and compiling with Delphi XE8 will let all works. 
NB2: Tried to override the DataModule's create event to open the query there. Same results.

Update: if I Set Query.FetchOptions.Mode to 'fmAll' it works.

Update2: Discovered that it doesn't commit becouse when the datamodule opens the query, the property InTransaction of the connection become **True**, otherwise it is set to **False**.

Do someone know what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug some people has, so I reported it. If you can reproduce it with a sample program or as find anything causing (or solving) it, please complete this https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-21411

The issue has just been closed as "resolved" by Embarcadero. It will probable present in a future hotfix.

Answer (score -1):

I'm facing the exact same issue here with Delphi v10.2 on an Oracle DB.
It's interesting to note that i don't see this behavior on all test environements.

I'm using FDMonitor to get details about the transaction process and I can see in the logs that on the environements that fail to commit the transaction imidieatly, there is a 'ACommit' value on the Query that is set to False while being set to True on the environements where it works fine.
This is strange.
The old version of my app that is compiled with delphi version prior to 10.2 works on ALL environements.

Regards,

Comment: *Me, too* isn't an answer.